# Use a class in two different project : decoder exception

Tags: xcode, swift, nskeyedarchiver, nscoder, nskeyedunarchiver

I have an exception using this code ;

```
let readingData = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data) as? [ExternalProjectClass]
```

The message in the console :

> cannot decode object of class (MyIOSApp.ExternalProjectClass) for key (NS.objects); the class may be defined in source code or a library that is not linked'

I use 'ExternalProjectClass' class in 2 project in the same workplace. In MyApp application (mac version). Otherwise I can use my class normally, I only have problems with coding.

I know how poor is my english. I hope somebody can help me.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Swift class names have namespaces, and the default namespace is module name. So if you move the archive from an app to another, the class name differs.

You could put `@objc(ExternalProjectClass)` attribute on your class, so it is called `ExternalProjectClass` as far as NSCoder considers.

```
@objc(ExternalProjectClass) class ExternalProjectClass: NSObject, NSCoding { ... }
```